# Transloco provideTranslocoScope don't work in angular 17 standalone component

Tags: angular-standalone-components, transloco, angular17

I have an angular 17 standalone app.
Translation with Transloco works well from the assets/i18n folder, but I nead different files for different components.

I tried using the providers in the route

path: 'home',
loadComponent: () =>  import('./pages/home/home.component').then((m) => m.HomeComponent),
providers: [ provideTranslocoScope('home')]`

and in the component, but I don't get the content of the translations in i18n/home directory.